# Python: Why does Substring [1:] work on a single char string

Tags: python, string, substring

I am learning python and I confused on why getting a string subset using the code below works.

s = 'a'
print(s[1:])

Since this is a string of length one  s[0:] would work since python is 0 indexed. Can somebody help explain why the s[1:] works?

My understanding of substrings is as follows:

string[start:end] = Get all characters from index start to end-1

string[:end] = Get all characters from the beginning of the string to end-1

string[start:] = Get all characters from index start to the end of the string

string[start:end:step] = Get all characters from start to end-1 discounting every step character

Comment: s = 'a' print(s[1:])    It does not work. Nothing is displayed.  Do you have any precondition? Which editor do you use?

Comment: Prints nothing is not the sane as does not work.

Answer (score -1):

You've already explained it

- `string[:end]` = Get all characters from the beginning of the string to `end-1` In this case,
- `s = 'a'` - the length of `s = 1`
- `print(len(s))` - this will result 1
- and you are doing `s[1:]`  -  print the characters from the start to the `end-1`,if you try `s[0:]` - will display - `a`